# How to append data coming from JSON to a particular parent in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, json, swift

Here I am having response from server data but here I need to display as shown in image below in shipping method section which in this carrier title will have sub methods in which it need to display in number of rows in section and for section title carrier title will be named and here method title needs to be appended from a particular carrier title with same names can anyone help me how to implement this ?

The code already I tried is

```
do
            {
                let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String : Any]]
                self.responseData = array!
                print(self.responseData)

            }
            catch let error
            {
                print("json error:", error)
            }
            for item in self.responseData {
                let dict = item
                let array = dict["carrier_title"]
                self.keyString.append(array as! String)
                let doubleRemoving = Set(self.keyString)
                print(doubleRemoving)
            }
            let status = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
            self.keyStatusCode = status
            print(status)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

here is my server response

```
[
  {
    "carrier_code": "flatrate",
    "method_code": "flatrate",
    "carrier_title": "Flat Rate",
    "method_title": "Fixed",
    "amount": 0,
    "base_amount": 0,
    "available": true,
    "error_message": "",
    "price_excl_tax": 0,
    "price_incl_tax": 0
  },
  {
    "carrier_code": "flatrate",
    "method_code": "flatrate",
    "carrier_title": "Flat Rate",
    "method_title": "Base",
    "amount": 0,
    "base_amount": 0,
    "available": true,
    "error_message": "",
    "price_excl_tax": 0,
    "price_incl_tax": 0
  },
  {
    "carrier_code": "tablerate",
    "method_code": "bestway",
    "carrier_title": "Best Way",
    "method_title": "Table Rate",
    "amount": 0,
    "base_amount": 0,
    "available": true,
    "error_message": "",
    "price_excl_tax": 0,
    "price_incl_tax": 0
  },
  {
    "carrier_code": "tablerate",
    "method_code": "bestway",
    "carrier_title": "Best Way",
    "method_title": "Worldwide Expedited",
    "amount": 0,
    "base_amount": 0,
    "available": true,
    "error_message": "",
    "price_excl_tax": 0,
    "price_incl_tax": 0
  },
  {
    "carrier_code": "tablerate",
    "method_code": "bestway",
    "carrier_title": "Best Way",
    "method_title": "Worldwide Express Saver",
    "amount": 0,
    "base_amount": 0,
    "available": true,
    "error_message": "",
    "price_excl_tax": 0,
    "price_incl_tax": 0
  }
```

[image]